# Salesforce CMS: Change Default Font color

Tags: lightning-experience, experience-cloud, salesforce-cms

**Question:**
I would like to know how to change font-color of text within body of News content-type within Salesforce CMS.

**Context:**
Currently I am unable to see any option within Salesforce CMS related to font-color in content editor in editing mode nor can I see any HTML tag editor mode whereby I can give HTML tags to control look and feel of text.

**Goal:**
The CMS news content will be displayed in Salesforce Experience Cloud site using "CMS Single Item" lightning component, but there is no font-color option provided for any text fields except for Metadata fields which does not reflect in my testing.

Regards,

Sourabh